# pymongo cursor to Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert my mongodb cursor to pandas dataframe. I want to avoid the use of lists directly using `data = list(collection.find())` but it goes out of memory, occupies a lot of memory. suggest me an efficient way to use lists or an alternative solution for this.

I have used a list to convert in pandas dataframe. It goes out of memory and stops the execution.

```
collection = db.get_collection('xxxyyyzzz')
data = collection.find()
for i in data:
   lst = pd.DataFrame(list.append(data))
```

I want to convert cursor to dataframe.

Comment: What is the size of the collection? You may want to open a chucksize, process it, then open another chunk, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield` to iterate over the cursor. [Read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators). Basically `yield` would process one item at a time, rather than saving everything in a memory.

```
def get_cursor():
    collection = db.get_collection('xxxyyyzzz')
    return collection.find()

def get_data_frames(cursor):
    for a_document in cursor:
        yield pd.DataFrame(list.append(data))

cursor = get_cursor()

for df in get_data_frames(cursor):
    // Do whatever
```